# How to change the font family of whole body in query mobile.?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to change the font family of whole application.
I am able to change the the font size. But now I need to change font type in my application. How can I do this?

From here I change the font:

```html
div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Display Font:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option>Select Font</option>
        <option value="9">9 px</option>
        <option value="10">10 px</option>
        <option value="11">11 px</option>
        <option value="12">12 px</option>
        <option value="13">13 px</option>
        <option value="14">14 px</option>
        <option value="15">15 px</option>
        <option value="16">16 px</option>
        <option value="17">17 px</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on('change', '#select-choice-1', function() {

    var style;
    var font = $(this).val();
    if ($('head').find('style.font').length === 0) {
        style = $('<style class="font">.font { font-size: ' + font + 'px !important; }</style>');
        $('head').append(style);
        $('body *').addClass('font');
    } else {
        $('body *').removeClass('font');
        $('style.font').empty();
        style = '.font { font-size: ' + font + 'px !important; }';
        $('style.font').append(style);
        $('body *').addClass('font');
    }
});
```

Now  I need to change the font family how to do that?

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Display Font:</label>
     <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
         <option>Select Font family</option>
         <option value="AntiquaAntiqua">AntiquaAntiqua</option>
         <option value="Arial"> Arial </option>
         <option value="Blackletter">Blackletter</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I don't know whether classesToChange variable contain all classes which need to be changed, but it works fine for me.

HTML:

```
<select id='select-choice-1'>
  <option>Select Font family</option>
  <option value="AntiquaAntiqua">AntiquaAntiqua</option>
  <option value="Arial"> Arial </option>
  <option value="Blackletter">Blackletter</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#select-choice-1").change(function(){
  var fontFamily = $(this).val() || "Arial"; 
  var classesToChange = ".ui-body-c,.ui-btn-text,.ui-li-divider,.ui-header,.ui-li,.panel";
  $(classesToChange).css("font-family", fontFamily);
});
```